# Finding the maximum value between two points in a column in a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to find the maximum value between two points in a column within an array.
I've tried to find examples on google but I only see np.max, np.maximum, and np.amax which seems to calculate over the entire axis rather than two points within the axis.
I fear the answer is incredibly obvious and I'm just not seeing it.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

```
data = np.random.uniform(low=0.0005, high=0.001, size=(20,2))
#find maximum value between data[5][1] and data[15][1]
```

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you just want the max of the slice `data[5:15, 1].max()`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am looking for. Sorry for such a basic question I am just learning numpy!